# UIDeviceOrientationDidChange only works with iPhone 7

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to detect the orientation change in a certain ViewController. I use the notification and a custom function. With iPhone 7 (running iOS 10.2) every time the notification changes the rotated function is being called. But while using iPhone 6 (running 9.3) or iPhone 6s (running 10.0) the function is being called only **once**, when the screen loads, but not when I turn around the phone.

Code:

```
func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Quite a chance you locked rotation in your device. This icon with circled arrow once you swipe from bottom to bring basic settings menu. If it's highlighted then rotation is locked and no signal will be send, as user wants everything to be in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the notification in the `viewWillAppear` function and it should work just fine. Works fine for me on devices available on the simulator. Actually the view DidLoad function is called only once when the view controller appears for the first time. Whereas the view will appear will be called everytime the view controller is about to be loaded.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
 }
```